# Advice for validation approach LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, validation, child-to-parent, parent-to-child

Hello guys I have being working on a LWC custom form that includes several child components, where each of them contains lightning-inputs, lightning-comboboxes, etc... And in the parent component I have a button that validated the inputted data.

The problem is that the parent component has a logic that allows the user display the child components he wants and I need to apply a validation to check if the required lighting-inputs from the display components the user wanted to be shown and not for the rest of hidden components.

Could someone tell me how to apply this approach? Could someone put an example at least with one child component and a parent component? Could someone tell me how to apply validation?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, in every child component expose same function

```
validate() {
   // logic to validate this specific component, returns true/false
   // assuming you are using lightning-input cmp
   const cmps = this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input');
   let valid = true;
   cmps.forEach(cmp => valid &= cmp.validate());
   return valid;
}
```

then in the parent on the button click select all the children by

```
const children = this.template.querySelectorAll('some smart selector to get all the children cmp');
```

This will get only those which are present in the dom, so if they are hidden they won't be selected.
Then you can call the `validate` function on every cmp

```
let valid = true;
children.forEach(cmp => valid &= cmp.validate());
```

Comment: Could you put an example of how to validate the fields that are required?

Comment: Updated, please see the documentation of lightning-input component, there definitely is a snippet of how to validate the component.

Comment: sorry, I did not explained well... I don´t need to validate the values I need to validate if the required fields are filled by the user

Comment: Yes, this is the way, if the lightning-field is required then the `validate` returns true if it is populated, false if not. (plus some extra validation depending on the type...)